# New "Definition" tag

Tags: discussion

On [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16910/what-is-the-difference-between-sensative-and-non-sensative-altimeters), I added [definition](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition). Is that a tag we should have?

The summary would be something like:

> Definitions of common aviation terms for reference by those new to the industry

Or something to that effect

Comment: I feel like `terminology` is already pretty close but it may be nice to have a tag to group `definition` questions.

Comment: On the other hand also having `phraseology` seems to be confusing already.

Comment: Maybe we pick one to be the `primary` tag and make the other two synonyms? Frankly, I just didn't come up with [tag:terminology] at all when I was trying to tag my question, and I'm not sure that [tag:phraseology] is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

"Meta" tags are commonly frowned-upon on SE sites. That is, tags which describe the question or the format of the question, rather than the topic of the question. Tags mainly serve to tell you if you would be interested in the question: that's why you can subscribe to your favourite tags, or ignore ones you're not interested in. I don't think a *definition* tag, whatever its name, would serve that purpose. It would merely make work for high-rep users and moderators to edit questions to add and remove the tag.

The answer to "Is this a tag we should have?" is generally the same as the answer to, "Would people subscribe to this tag?"

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I like [definition](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) - it feels like almost every "What is XXX?" question could have that tag attached to it, it doesn't really provide much useful information for categorization.

[flight-instruments](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flight-instruments) might be better? (We already have [gyroscopic-instruments](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gyroscopic-instruments), by analogy to that [static-instruments](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/static-instruments) would be logical as well, but probably confusing to anyone who doesn't know the terms "pitot" & "static".)

Answer (score 0):

As Dan [said](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1719/62), tags are there to help people subscribe to topics they're interested in, and they can also be a way to list all the questions in a certain subject area to see what's already been asked (or just to browse out of interest).

In that context, I don't think that [definition](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) is useful. There's no obvious subject area commonality for "what does X mean?" questions and I think it's unlikely that anyone would subscribe to it. Even if people are interested in the definitions of aerodynamic terms (for example), their real interest is aerodynamics, not definitions.

But I do think there's a purpose for [terminology](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) because - for one thing - aviation terminology isn't consistent around the world. I assume (I may be wrong) that for some people, differences in aviation terms around the world are an interesting and helpful topic (think international flights).

As for [phraseology](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phraseology), it's a specific, well-defined topic about using the correct words and phrases in radio communications so I think there shouldn't be much issue with that one.